# Why the percentage height doesn't work in my CSS?

Tags: html, css

I know this has been asked many times, but I'm stuck trying to get % height of an element to work.  My understanding is the if the parent element has a height specified then setting a % height on the child element should work.  Unfortunately I have tried to get this to work but I must be missing something.

```
body{
  border-radius: 10;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.child-element{
   height: 50%;
   margin: none;
   background-color: gray;
 }
```

Where I have:

```
<body>
  <div class="child-element">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/59x6dqhh/

Comment: There are a couple of wrong syntax should be corrected: 1) `border-radius:10` you need to add `px` or so i.e. `border-radius:10px` but you won't be able to see it in your demo as it's all in white. 2) `margin:none` is not valid, again it needs a value, i.e. `margin:0` or `0px` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a parent element `html` for `body` tag also needs the `height` to be set.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Simplified demo below (removed unnecessary rules and reset default body margin too).

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.child-element {
    height: 50%;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="child-element"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's brilliant - thanks - What I hadn't stated was that between body element and child-element I had a container element whose height hadn't been specified.  this breaks the chain of height and so the child-element didn't work.  Setting a height on the container element meant that it worked.  thanks

Comment: Yep, glad to hear that works, like we mentioned that **all** the parent elements need the `height` to be specified.

Comment: Sorry I had tried to accept it straight away but SO told me I had to wait x amount of time and I haven't been back on SO since

Comment: @LindaKeating no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to present the available browser client area as containing a single content rectangle (rather than having a tall one that scrolls), I prefer to do:

```
body {
top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
overflow: hidden; position: overflow;
}
```

If the aim is to have a child panel that builds height from nothing, then you need to be aware that the height of objects is based on width of parent, not height when the object is not absolute or fixed position. It's possible to build a square as follows:

```css
.square {
 width: 20em;
    background: cyan;
}
.square:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.square:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="square">Square</div>
```

You can change the aspect ratio of the block by changing the amount of padding.

Hope this helps.

Mark